# WSO2 EI 6.1.1 - How to use local transport between esb and dss

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to call a DSS service from REST API or Proxy Service with local transport and receive this error:

**The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is local://services/Personas**

If I call Proxy to Proxy works OK, but not from Proxy to DSS Proxy or REST API to DSS Proxy.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Local+Transport
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sample+268%3A+Proxy+Services+with+the+Local+Transport

Thank you,
JP

Comment: Is the local transport enabled for this data service ? Usually the .ds file has an attribute right on top that lists the transports where it will be exposed.

Comment: Yes. It's enabled. Thanks.

Comment: `local://services/Personas` - there should be 3 slashes - not 2, after local: `local:///services/Personas` If this is not the cause, perhaps the WS-Action?

Comment: I tried both and it's the same. Thank you.

Comment: Did you configure transport Sender and Receiver as described in documentation?

Comment: Yes. Someone of you have this working? Calling a dss service from an esb sequence with local transport with EI 6.1.1?

Comment: I do this a lot. If u call proxy to proxy,  then by default WSOESB generates wsdl pretty simple. It has only mediate method, and accept everything, despite WSOESB generate his own wsdl with methods specific to service. Possibly using unique namespace. That is why calling DSS service from Proxy needs more attention, and properly form request to DSS service.

Comment: Error message states, operation u call in DSS service doesn't exists. Means body of request to DSS service is not correct. Log mesage you send to DSS service, get wsdl from DSS service and extract schema and validate logged request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.
I used local://services/Personas.
Set the soap11 as address type, and set the Header Action to the necessary operation.

Thank you all the people that tried to helped me.

JP